# Reading Alpha Channels from each Pixel in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

how can I read from an image the RGBA values in QT?

I hope that somebody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt5 there is a **`QImage::pixel(int x, int y)`** method. You can access the RGBA values of the return value via the `qBlue`, `qRed`, `qGreen` and `qAlpha` functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to format RGBA [using `convertToFormat`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#convertToFormat) as below:

```
    QImage myImage( ":/Images/images.jpg" );
    myImage = myImage.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
```

Now you can get R,G,B,A values in sequence with proper data alignment as below:

```
    uchar *bits = myImage.bits();    
    for (int i = 0; i < (myImage.width() * myImage.height() * 4); i++)
    {
        qDebug() << (int) bits[i];    // Here printing the RGBA values in sequence
    }
```

This will give you R,G,B,A of every pixel after every 4th cycle.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming an initialized `QImage mImage`

```
for( int y = 0; y < height; y++ ) {
    QRgb *lineOut = (QRgb *)mImage.scanLine(y);
    for( int x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
        int r = 255, g = 0, b = 255;
        lineOut[x] = qRgb(r, g, b);
    }
}
```